# Is there any way to depend on any ref of git in pubspec of flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I write two flutter packages `A` and `B`. `A` depends on `B` using `git`,

```yaml
# A pubspec.yaml
dependencies:
  B:
    git: xxxxx
```

If I depend on both `A` and `B` in a project using git `url` and `ref`,

```yaml
# App pubspec.yaml
dependencies:
  A:
    git:
      url: xxxx
      ref: 0.0.1
  B:
    git:
      url: xxxx
      ref: 0.1.0
```

I get an error w `pub get`

> Because demo_app depends on A from git which depends on B from git, B from git {url: xxxx, ref: HEAD, path: .} is required.
> So, because demo_app depends on B from git {url: xxxx, ref: 0.1.0, path: .}, version solving failed.

I can use `dependency_overrides` to resolve this conflict. But is there a more elegant way, such as using agnostic ref, like `ref: any` for package `A`?

Comment: Does omitting `ref` help?

Comment: @jamesdlin Of course it works, but this means HEAD branch of `B` package is used. As a developer of flutter package, I should not restrict which ref the business side uses. So I hope to handle it internally.

Comment: Generally `git` dependencies are meant to be a temporary means to use development versions of packages before they've been published to `pub.dev`.  If you don't use `pub.dev`, you lose the ability to have version constraints.  If the package is available on `pub.dev`, I suppose you could try using `B: any`. In principle, if you don't care about `B`'s version at all, then you shouldn't care where it comes from.  I don't know offhand if `B: any` could be satisfied by a package consumed from Git, though.